# OpenCV: control video playback with both keyboard and mouse

Tags: python, opencv, user-interface, video, playback

I'd like to be able to play a video (that automatically stops at some fixed frames), and I want to be able to play/stop either using keyboard or mouse. However, it seems that opencv does not provide a function to wait both a keyboard event or a mouse event. I saw there exists a function `setMouseCallback` but I'm not sure how to use it to make sure that I don't have any conflicts between the keyboard and the mouse. Am I supposed to create a thread that receive messages from both the mouse and the keyboard, or is there something simpler? Otherwise, is there any more suited library to play/seek/stop a video precisely on a given frame?

**EDIT**
I tried to implement a solution based on threads, and I do `action = self.queue.get()` instead of `cv2.waitKey(...)`, but then nothing is displayed on screen. Also, if I do `cv2.waitKey(1)` before, I get an empty frame, and the `cv2.waitKey` located in other threads does not detect any keypress...

Comment: sounds like you want a proper GUI. OpenCV has rudimentary GUI facilities that _work_ but it's not perfect. you need an actual GUI library. -- you can set a flag (variable in your code) from the mouse callback and react to that in the loop that contains waitKey.

Comment: Hum, too bad. Do you have some suggestions on GUI which would allow me to easily stop on a precise frame? Concerning your idea, the problem is that waitKey may wait forever for a key to be pressed, so  don't see how this flag could help at it won't make waitKey continue. Maybe I could try to create various threads.

Comment: simple, waitKey with small maximum delay, or pollKey for no delay at all. as for "precise frame", now you'll have to use ffmpeg directly as well. opencv uses ffmpeg, but ffmpeg is so badly documented that opencv can't use the "seeking" apis of ffmpeg properly.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz oh, you mean having many small wait... It may work, but it's not great in term of efficiency I guess as it risks to consume CPU cycles for no reasons... but it's worth trying it, I'll give it a try thanks.

Comment: I'll tell you a secret: many GUI loops work like that. don't worry. practically, a waitKey(1) will wait an entire scheduler time slice, which can be 10-15 milliseconds. it spends most time in a very short sleep() call and checks for new messages in between sleep calls. in your case I wouldn't recommend *pollKey* then because that does no sleep at all.